# Unnecessary strerror_l calls

Tags: c++, profiling

```
#include <iostream>
int main(){
    for(int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++){
        std::string from = "hello";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This code produce some strerror_l calls inside of std::string constructor. It's sample code, inside real project it called much more times (profiled with google pprof). What is it and how can I avoid these calls?

Test environment:

`debian 6.0.1, g++ 4.4.5 and g++ 4.9.2` - no strerror_l calls

`debian 8.6, g++ 4.9.2` - several calls

Ways to reproduce (google pprof required):

Build with profiler: 
`g++ question.cpp -lprofiler`

Get profile data: `CPUPROFILE=/tmp/question.out /tmp/a.out`

Build call graph: `google-pprof --pdf /tmp/a.out question.out > output.pdf`

Comment: `std::string` obviously needs to allocate memory for its contents. If it fails, as part of its error handling it must be calling `strerror_l`. You cannot "avoid" this. This is how it works. If you don't want calls to `strerror_l`, don't use `std::string`.

Comment: The gcc 4 does not support small string optimizations. Each string allocates memory there. Perhaps memory manager (or its instrumentation with profiler) causes lot of small allocations to fragment memory so badly that these constructors start to fail.

Comment: @ÖöTiib -- it would take a **really bad** memory manager to get badly fragmented on a simple pattern of repeatedly allocating and immediately freeing a block of exactly the same size. Plus, if the allocation failed it would throw an exception.